# Getting all Magento categories with their names

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to get all the categories in my Magento website. I've achieved that but they only come back with limited data. I need the name of the category which I'm missing. I've tried using `addAttributeToSelect` but that doesn't make any difference. Here is my code.

```
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->getData();
print_r($cats);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is OK. Except the `print_r`.
You are printing a collection object and you need to print the items in it.

```
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
         ->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*');//or use 'name' instead of '*'

foreach ($cats as $cat){
    echo 'ID: '.$cat->getId().' Name: '.$cat->getName().'<br />';
}
```

Comment: I was using `getData`, but on the entire collection. Now that I loop over each one and then call `getData` it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

http://magentotutorialbeginners.blogspot.in/2014/03/magento-all-categories-with-their-names.html

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('id')
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
->addAttributeToSelect('url')
->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');

foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    if ($category->getIsActive()) { 
        $name = $category->getName();
    }
}
```